# How should I read one char in C when spaces should be ignored?

Tags: c

I should create with C a function, which reads a one char and returns it. The function should return 0, if reading fails. The space chars should be ignored by the function. If given char is ' ', the next next char should be read until a non-space char is given.

I have understod that scanf ignores spaces, so this cannot be used. And I use getchar how can I know if reading fails? Any ideas?

Comment: from getchar() documentation - `If some other reading error happens, the function also returns EOF, but sets its error indicator (ferror) instead.`

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` does not skip spaces (white-spaces) in case of character reading. To use `scanf` without reading spaces you can do as follows:

```
scanf(" %c", ch) // ch is char type  
       ^Notice the space before %c.
```

To use `getchar` you have to check for the space

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar) != EOF)   // This will also check the reading failed by getchar.
{
    if(ch == ' ')
        continue;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ignore white-space like `' '` or `'\t` or `'\n'`, etc. , use `" %c"` in `scanf()` like suggested by @haccks, and use the return value from `scanf()` to determine success.

```
int Read1_NotWhiteSpace(char *ch) {
  int retval = scanf(" %c", ch);
  if (retval == 1) return 1;
  return 0; // fail
}
```

If you need to ignore only a `' '` (space), use `int getchar(void)`

```
int Read1_NotSpace(char *ch) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
  if (c == EOF) return 0; // fail
  *ch = (char) c;
  return 1;
}
```

Note: OP was not clear on how to return with success.  Could return `ch` on success, but then unable to distinguish the rare read of `'\0'`.  The below simple returns `ch` on success.

```
int Read1_NotSpaceAlternate(void) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
  if (c == EOF) return 0; // fail
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getchar` fails, it returns `EOF`, usually -1.